# Update broke graphics driver, no GL, no Unity 3D, GeForce 610M

Tags: 12.04, unity, drivers, nvidia, graphics

About a month ago an automatic update and a seven day-streak with no reboot somehow broke my graphics capabilities, rendering me Unity 2D'd and video-game-less. I suspect it is to do with driver versions or kernel modules not loading.

Please help. :)

### What I have tried

Installing/reinstalling `nvidia-331`, `nvidia-331-updates`, `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-quantal`, and others, rebooting lots of times.

### Technical info

Distro: Ubuntu  12.04 lts 64 bit
Graphics card: Nvidia GeForce 610M

`uname -a`:

```
Linux XXXX 3.5.0-54-generic #81~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 04:02:22 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`lspci -v`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: da000000-daffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d0000000-00000000d9ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3901
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at db000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
    Memory at db600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at db614000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei
    Kernel modules: mei

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at db619000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at db610000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: db500000-db5fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: db400000-db4fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at db618000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    I/O ports at 4088 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4094 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4080 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4090 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4060 [size=32]
    Memory at db617000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
    Memory at db615000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 4040 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [GeForce 610M] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3901
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at da000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Memory at d8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at <ignored> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidia_331_updates, nouveau, nvidiafb

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3979
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at db500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=128]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx

03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device 0587
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at db400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl, bcma
```

`lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nvidia              10670775  0 
bnep                   18240  2 
rfcomm                 47562  12 
parport_pc             32867  0 
ppdev                  17114  0 
lib80211_crypt_tkip    17391  0 
wl                   3074942  0 
coretemp               13642  0 
kvm                   422160  0 
uvcvideo               78117  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13221  0 
videobuf2_core         33025  1 uvcvideo
videodev              125126  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
aesni_intel            51134  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32532  1 
cryptd                 20531  2 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
videobuf2_vmalloc      12861  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13405  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
btusb                  22432  0 
snd_hda_codec_conexant    62363  1 
rts5139               350620  0 
bluetooth             212001  24 bnep,rfcomm,btusb
aes_x86_64             17256  1 aesni_intel
binfmt_misc            17541  1 
joydev                 17694  0 
snd_hda_intel          34063  3 
snd_hda_codec         135141  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              17765  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                97523  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13325  0 
snd_rawmidi            30750  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14900  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61931  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14498  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
microcode              23030  0 
cfg80211              208382  1 wl
dm_multipath           23306  0 
lib80211               14382  2 lib80211_crypt_tkip,wl
i915                  539800  2 
drm_kms_helper         49259  1 i915
drm                   290595  3 i915,drm_kms_helper
psmouse               102759  0 
alx                    73500  0 
snd                    83674  16 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
mei                    41410  0 
scsi_dh                14589  1 dm_multipath
i2c_algo_bit           13565  1 i915
serio_raw              13216  0 
mdio                   13808  1 alx
ideapad_laptop         18235  0 
soundcore              15092  1 snd
sparse_keymap          13891  1 ideapad_laptop
mac_hid                13254  0 
snd_page_alloc         18573  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
lpc_ich                17145  0 
video                  19653  1 i915
nls_iso8859_1          12714  1 
lp                     17800  0 
parport                46563  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
ahci                   25869  3 
libahci                31434  1 ahci
```

**ETA:** `lspci -v` for `lspci`

### ETA2: @mchid's answer

I ran the commands as prescribed. No change seem to have occurred, I am still in Unity 2D, and my test-case game (mednafen on a GBA rom) reports GLX to be broken still.

Closing `lightdm` reported the following:

```
[ 2455.794755] bbswitch: No suitable _DSM call found.
```

### ETA3: @mchid's comment (see below)

`glxinfo` in terminal-7 (i.e. in the "main" one):

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
name of display: :0.0
```

Comment: the only error shown has to do with bumblebee

Comment: what does `glxinfo` say

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
lspci -v
```

Will tell you what driver is in use for each adapter. It looks like you are only using i915 intel graphics right now.

If the kernel module nvidia is not loading . . . use CTRL + ALT + F2 to enter a text session, login with your username and password and then type the following commands:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

(if you are using gdm substitute gdm for lightdm instead)

```
sudo modprobe nvidia
sudo service lightdm start
```

Please post any errors.

---

Okay try:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core
```

and if that doesn't work, make a backup of and then remove /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so and reboot

source http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930433

Comment: I did as you asked, report in ETA.

Comment: @KarlDamgaardAsmussen I have updated the answer, take a look at the link also.